# Automatically uploading files into AWS Linux from Windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, automation

Short Version: I need a code which automatically uploads a file into AWS Linux server.

Longer Version: There is a software called MinKNOW which does DNA sequencing and it takes hours to complete a single sequencing. As an output it creates a file in fastq format. The output file gets bigger while MinKNOW does sequencing. I want to write a code which uploads these files into my AWS Linux server automatically once in a while.

Comment: You have not mentioned much details about what kind of system your MinKNOW software runs (Linux?, Windows?) and if your long process produces a single file or many files... All these are key points to help you.

Just to give you a simple solution: you might want to review the rsync tool over SSH (e.g. here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-transfer-files-with-rsync-over-ssh/ ), so you sync a local directory with a remote system.This is an answer as general as your question; so it might not fit perfectly your specific case as we don't know much about your situation.

Comment: Thank for your answer Ramon, I run MinKnow on Windows and it produces many files in one run. I would be very glad if you have more specific solution. Thanks again